# How long does it usually take to format a 2TB external HD using ext4 and gparted?

Tags: external-hard-drive, formatting, gparted, ext4

How long does it usually take to format a 2TB external HD using ext4 and gparted?

Comment: ext4 can be formatted in a defered way, where most of formatting commences in background while the filesystem can already be used after a very short initalization period. Using `mkfs.ext4`, the option would be `-E lazy_itable_init=1`, and this even is a default setting it seems. I don't know how to make `gparted` using this option, but maybe it is possible. Using this feature, a 2GB partition gets available after about one minute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It depends. Are you just formatting, or formatting and wiping the drive? How is the drive connected? USB 1/2/3? Firewire? eSATA?

Are there other partitions that need to be cleared off first?

Honestly, its probably going to take a while, so be patient.

Answer (score 6):

It takes 17 minutes and 16 seconds.

Using: Ubuntu 10.04 amd64; gparted 0.7.1; mke2fs 1.41.11; USB2; a Western Digital Elements 2TB drive. This is just for the format; the partitioning was done in an earlier step.

Your mileage may vary.

Comment: I came here to ask an uncannily similar question; I could ask it separately, but it would probably be a duplicate.  I am stuck on the partition step.  I told it to delete the pre-existing NTFS parition and create an ~1700 GB ext4 and ~300 GB ntfs.  However, it has been on the "delete partition" step (for the pre-exisitng NTFS) for a very long time (well over a day).  I am on a E1505, with Kubuntu 9.10, and USB 2.0.  I have the same drive.

Comment: Deleting the partition should be (almost) instantaneous. It might be an idea to try unplugging and replugging your drive; if that doesn't work then try rebooting; and if *that* doesn't work, maybe download and boot from the gparted Live CD?

Comment: thanks.  That's what I originally thought, but then I rationalized that it might be zeroing the partition (although it was *still* really long).  When I canceled, it segfaulted and printed `gpartedbin[17137]: segfault at 6b202d54 ip 06e671ef sp bfc1fb10 error 4 in libc-2.10.1.so[6dfc000+13e000]`.  Of course, it shouldn't segfault regardless.  But I'm not sure if it did so because I canceled, or it was already in "trouble".  The fact that it took so long makes me suspect the latter.  At any rate, when I check now, the partition table is empty.

Comment: The creation of the two new partitions was fairly quick and uneventful.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that `mke2fs` has to write data (e.g. for inode tables, journal, superblocks and accounting information) till only about 5% of the size of the filesystem and a write speed of 100 MB/s it would take under 17 minutes!